# Website not responsive on Galaxy S5 browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm using jquery to remove a div to make my home screen look different on small screens and it's working fine on a Macbook Air and Iphone X. However on Android the div isn't removed and replaced as intended. This is the address for the website draft:

http://projetocc.learningtodom.com/

This is the code for the jquery bit:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 750px)").matches) {
        $('.desktop').remove();
    }
});

$(function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 750px)").matches) {
        $('.mobiles').remove();
    }
});
  </script>
```

Let me know if you need me to post some css code as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any success with your javascript approach, maybe you could consider using CSS and media queries. You may find that it's easier and gives more consistent results.

Simply add a viewport meta tag in the head of your document

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
</head>
```

And then in your CSS add the following

```
    @media(max-width:750px){
    .desktop{
        display:none;
    }
   }

   @media(min-width:751px){
     .mobiles{
         display:none;
     }
   }
```

I made a minor change to one of your breakpoints. With the code you had posted, both the mobile and desktop divs would be hidden at 750px.

I hope this helps!